# How to continuously push user input data into $_SESSION array and then retrieve it?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to get my head around the way `PHP` sessions work. I am simply trying a hangman game where the first player inputs a secret word, a second player then starts to guess one letter at a time.

Let's says that the secret word is `cat`, player two tries, `c` then `a` then `s`. I would like the final output to be `c a _`.

```
  <?php
session_start();

global $word;
global $guess;
global $hangman;


if (isset($_POST['player1'], $_POST['word'])) {
    $_SESSION['word'] = $_POST['word'];
    $word = $_SESSION['word'];
}

if (isset($_POST['player2'], $_POST['guess'])) {
    $_SESSION['guess'] = $_POST['guess'];
    $guess = $_SESSION['guess'];
}

$counter = 0;
$word = strtolower($_SESSION['word']);
$guess = strtolower($_SESSION['guess']);
echo $word . "<br>";
$found = [];

$counter = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
    if ($counter < strlen($word)) {
        if (strpos($word[$i], $guess) !== false) {
            $found[] = $guess;
            $counter++;
        } else {
            $found[] = " _ ";
        }
    }
}

  print_r($found);
```

Instead of printing out all the contents the `found` array, I am only getting one single letter to print every time. However, I would like to see the full concatenated string as I've mentioned above.

---

#### Here is what the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: What's up with the `global` keywords? Is this code in some function or class method? Using `global` is something you should try to avoid at all cost.

Comment: Not at the moment, but eventually, that is the purpose.

Comment: `$_SESSION['guess'] = $_POST['guess'];`, this will overwrite any previous guesses that's stored in that session each time player2 makes a new guess.

Comment: How can I fix that ?

Comment: Make `$_SESSION['guesses']` into an array which you push new guesses into. Then you need to iterate through that array to replace the letters.

Comment: I made ` $_SESSION['guess'] = array(); `  and I am pushing all the new guesses, but its still not working.

Comment: If I were in your place, I would return the indexes array that this guess matches a character in the word... because as far as I understand the hidden code, that every time the use will guess new character, you will build the found[] from the beginning.

I would return an array of the indexes that this character found, and in the ui code if the sizeof(array) > 0, then just show this guess character.

So you will get your code reduced in the for loop and can set your session to the array of indexes.

Comment: To be honest, I have not been able to implement your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to continuously push user input data into $_SESSION array and then retrieve it?

An easy way to do that is by binding a variable with an element in the $_SESSION array.
This is a useful trick that you won't find in [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php).
A simple example:

```
$foo =& $_SESSION['foo'];
```

That assignment will bind `$foo` and `$_SESSION['foo']` to the same value,
so every update to `$foo` is also an update to `$_SESSION['foo']`.

Here is an example usage in the style of your hangman game:

```
<?php
session_start();

$word =& $_SESSION['word'];   //bind $word with $_SESSION['word']
$found =& $_SESSION['found']; //bind $found with $_SESSION['found']

if (isset($_REQUEST['word'])) {
    $word = str_split($_REQUEST['word']);
    $found = array_fill(0, count($word), '_');
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['guess'], $word, $found)) {
    $guess = array_fill(0, count($word), $_REQUEST['guess']);
    $found = array_replace($found, array_intersect($word, $guess));
}

echo join(' ', $found);
```

With the binding, the values of `$word` and `$found` will be saved as a part of the session data,
without the need to do `$_SESSION['word'] = $word;` and `$_SESSION['found'] = $found;` anywhere in the script.

Note that I use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` to make it easier to test with a browser.
Modify as desired.

Comment: Your post actually makes sense to me, especially that useful trick `$foo =& $_SESSION['foo'];`

Answer (score 0):

Make the $found as a string variable.Instead of pushing in $found[] ,concatenate $guess Like  $found .= $guess;

Answer (score 0):

You should save what was already found between requests, since now you are just searching the `$_SESSION['word']` for the char in the last request.

```
if ( isset($_POST['player1']) && !empty($_POST['word']) ) {
    $_SESSION['word'] = str_split( $_POST['word'] );
    // ceate empty array for storing the already found chars
    $_SESSION['found'] = str_split( str_repeat( " ", strlen($_POST['word']) ) );        
}

if ( isset($_POST['player2']) && !empty($_POST['guess']) ) {

    array_walk( $_SESSION['word'], function( $v, $k ) {
        if ( $v == $_POST['guess'] )
            $_SESSION['found'][$k] = $v;
    });
}


if ( $_SESSION['word'] == $_SESSION['found'] ) 
    echo 'Game Over';

print_r( $_SESSION['found'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your `$_SESSION['guess']` with:

```
$_SESSION['guess'] = $_POST['guess'];
```

on every submission.

I would recommend that you store your posted guesses as a subarray of letters like:

```
$_SESSION['guesses'][] = $_POST['guess'];
```

Then you will never overwrite earlier guesses.

This will mean you will have a session array with this type of structure:

```
$_SESSION=[
    'player1' => 'me',
    'word'    => 'cat',
    'player2' => 'myself',
    'guesses' => ['a','c']
];
```

From here, you can call `str_split()` on `$_SESSION['word']` and check for found/remaining letters using `$_SESSION['guesses']` and array comparison functions.

---

Here are some untested portions of code that may help you along...

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['player1'], $_SESSION['word'])) {  // no stored player1 or word
    if (!isset($_POST['player1'], $_POST['word'])) {  // no posted player1 or word
        // show form with player1 and word fields
    } else {
        $_SESSION=['player1'=>$_POST['player1'],'word'=>strtolower($_POST['word'])]; // store player1 and word
    }
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['player2'], $_SESSION['guesses'])){  // no stored player2 or guesses
    if (!isset($_POST['player2'], $_POST['guess'])) {  // no posted player2 or guess
        // show form with player2 and first guess
    } else {
        $_SESSION['player2'] = $_POST['player1'];  // store player2
        $_SESSION['guesses'] = [strtolower($_POST['guess'])];  // store guessed character as first element of subarray
    }
} elseif (isset($_POST['guess'])) {
    $_SESSION['guesses'][] = strtolower($_POST['guess']);  // store guessed character
}
```

And further down script here are some pieces...

```
$secret_letters=array_unique(str_split($_SESSION['word']));  // unique secret word letters
$found_letters=array_intersect($secret_letters,$_SESSION['guesses']);  // unique found letters
if($secret_letters===$found_letters){
    // player2 guessed all of the secret letters, set off fireworks
}else{
    // some useful bits of code...

    $not_yet_found=array_diff($secret_letters,$_SESSION['guesses']);
    $underscored=str_replace($not_yet_found,'_',$_SESSION['word']);  // e.g. 'ca_'
    $space_out=implode(' ',str_split($underscored));  // e.g. 'c a _'

    $wrong_letters=array_diff($_SESSION['guesses'],$secret_letters);  // letters guessed but not part of secret word
    // when count($wrong_letters) reaches your designated limit, then the guesser loses

    $avaliable_letters=array_diff(range('a','z'),$_SESSION['guesses']);
    $select="<select name=\"guess\"><option>".implode('</option><option>',$available_letters)."</option></select>";
}
```

I should also note, there are many ways to tackle this project.  You should have a look at `count_chars()`, it has multiple modes which you should research and consider.

There will be regex methods that may be helpful, but I won't open up that can for you.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem now. you didn't save or hold the previous guess because your `found[]` array variable is always empty.

try to save the found result in a session

and change this following line of code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
if ($counter < strlen($word)) {
    if (strpos($word[$i], $guess) !== false) {
        $found[] = $guess;
        $counter++;
    } else {
        $found[] = " _ ";
    }
}
}
```

TO:

```
$counterWord = strlen($word);
for ($i = 0; $i < $counterWord ; $i++) {
    if (strpos($word[$i], $guess) !== false) {
        $found[$i] = $guess; // $i indicates what index should be changed

    } else {

        if(!isset($found[$i])){
         $found[$i] = "_";

       }


}


$_SESSION['found'] = $found;
```

and add this line of code under the declaring of your `$found` array variable:

```
$found = [];
if(isset($_SESSION['found'])){ //checker if the variable is set and not empty
     $found = $_SESSION['found']; // getting the value of found and store it in found variable 
}
```

Comment: first what if this variable or session is not set? then !empty is not working this will return a error. second if the variable is isset and it doesnt have a value so no need to use the variable.

Comment: why i use $found[$i]? did you get the point of this code?
if not then ill explain it to you: what if the first guess word is not in the word? then it will create a `$found =array("_","_","_")` right?

second run if the guess is in the word then the $found array will be adding new iterated array `$found = array("_","_","_","c","a","_")`. right? because i store the found variable in session so it will retrieve the guess word.
so i use the index to indicate where array index it will be changed

Comment: ill put a comment for each line sorry if you cant understand the purpose of each line

Comment: Sorry, is it ok now?

Comment: int this first fiddel https://3v4l.org/EN584
you declared the found index thats why you dont need to use isset but in this case the $_SESSION['found'] is not yet declared so in the first run if you use !empty without isset this will return an error code.

Comment: in this point https://3v4l.org/jZLac
your array increment as the user guess new letter. i think in this one your confused. i indicate the $i as the index where does the letter be changed.

Comment: i get your point here i rather use isset than empty but in the other point you mention i think your the one who confused? did you check this out  https://3v4l.org/sOMUs

Comment: yeah forgotten https://3v4l.org/PjUTF here is the edited one. if you didnt use $i here ill show you what happen wait for a while

Comment: https://3v4l.org/HGSWm see this every guess does the user the array will increment and you cant indicate where index was it if it is correct

Comment: want to see it if i will not use that line of code: check this out https://3v4l.org/kUDMK

Comment: i think you didnt see this line of code:  `$_SESSION['found'] = $found;` i feed the found variable after checking so that if the user try to guess another letter we already have the result of his previous guess

Comment: hahaha what nonsense bro check the top question first. he says :  "the first player inputs a secret word, a second player then **starts to guess one letter at a time.**"


"**Instead of printing out all the contents the found array, I am only getting one single letter to print every time**. However, I would like to see the full concatenated string as I've mentioned above."

Comment: so how you will be retrieving the previous guess?** its an array** then you can just implode it if you need to print it out

Comment: first thing first:

i check if the `$_SESSION['found']` is set if not the `$found` variable is empty then after checking with the for loop i will feed the `$found` variable to `$_SESSION['found']` for the next guess. in the second guess it will check again if `$_SESSION['found']` is set if yes the `$found` variable will get the value of the `$_SESSION['found']` . and check the second guess letter in for loop. if seen then overwrite the `$found[]` with the use of `$i` we can change the exact location of the letter. example `$found[$i] ="_"` because of the first run.then change it to `$guess`

Comment: i didnt use `$_SESSION['guess']` because the user overwrite it for the sake of his need i just added a new SESSION for the storing of the found.